# Problem linking library. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: curl, codeblocks

C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Neutralized\project\Neutralized\Download.c|19|undefined reference to `*imp*_curl_global_init'|

How do I link the library?

I've linked this: ......\curl-7.21.2\lib\Debug\libcurl.lib

But it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify which compiler you were using but I'm going to guess it's gcc -- procedure isn't too different for other compilers.

First, make sure the import library is properly added under project->properties->linker tab. For gcc the switch to use is -lcurl. Second make sure the library search path is properly included -- that is the folder location of libcurl.lib must be in the -L< folder location > when linking. Otherwise the linker won't know where to find it.